# break out of iframe with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I have a page with an iframe, on the iframe page I have a img that opens up a fancybox. This works just fine, It's just that the modal box targets the iframe, giving only part of the whole page a dark overlay and centering the fancybox on the iframe instead of the whole page.

This is the code:

```
<img src="/img/icons/calendar.png" class="fancybox" id="fancyCalendar" />

<script>
    $j('#fancyCalendar').click(function() {
        $j.fancybox.open({
            href: 'calendar.html',
            type: 'iframe',
            padding: 5,
            width: 880,
            height: 335
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've tried these things, none worked:

- adding a target to the img
- making the img a link with a target
- prepending window.parent to the fancybox.open prepending
- window.parent.parent to the fancybox.open

I don't know what else I can try, does anybody know how to doe this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extend Fancybox inside an iFrame to outside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528177/extend-fancybox-inside-an-iframe-to-outside)

Comment: possible duplicate of [call Fancybox in parent from iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853727/call-fancybox-in-parent-from-iframe)

Comment: how to do it with fancybox v2.x http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987 including demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iframes are a browser separate window inside another browser, so you can't do what you're trying to do.

The only workaround, that works **only** if the iframe is on the same domain as the top frame, is to call the fancybox function of the parent frame.

Inside the iframe you call:

```
window.parent.openFancyBox(url, params...);
```

In the **parent** you've your local function

```
function openFancyBox(url, ....) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have first load content in a iframe, and then open it with plugin fancybox.